# Unable to fetch data from controller in multiple html page in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs-controller

I am trying to make a webpage.In that when a user login , a new html page("dashboard.html")opens in the view. This "dashboard.html" contains some links(links to other html pages).When user clicks on them a new html(say "page_3.html") page should open with data that is present in controller.this "page_3.html" is not fetching data from controller.Below is my code.

```js
<!-- controller.js   -->
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[ 'ngRoute' ]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){ 
       $routeProvider
       .when('/',{ 
          templateUrl: 'login.html' 
       })
       .when('/dashboard',{
           templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' 
    })
       .when('/page_3',{ 
          templateUrl: 'page_3.html' 
       })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo : '/'
       });
        
    });


    app.controller('app', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.item = "test";
        $scope.submit = function(){
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            }   
        };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Project</title>
            <script src="angular.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="controller.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app= "myApp" ng-controller="app">
            <div ng-view></div>   
        </body>
    </html>

    <!-- below is login.html page -->

    <div ng-controller="app">      
    <form action="/"> 
         <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
            </form>
    </div>

    <!-- below is my dashboard.html page -->
    <div ng-controller="app">
      <h1>Page_3</h1>
            <div><a href='page_3.html'>page_3</a></div>
        </div>
      
      <!-- below is page_3.html page -->

    <div ng-controller="app">
    <p>{{item}}</p>
    </div>
```

result : {{item}}

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could work with?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest avoiding the `ng-controller` directive and rather use the `controller` config object on your router?

```
.when('/page_3',{ 
  templateUrl: 'page_3.html',
  controller: "app"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your code:

1. Enable HTML 5 mode for [pushState via $locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)  for URLs like `/dashboard` and `/page_3`
2. Fix the problem where route is configured for `/page_3` but having a `a` tag pointed to `/page_3.html`

To get a working example:

- Add a base tag

  ```
  <base href="/">
  ```
- Enable html5 mode via locationProvider in a [config](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) block

  ```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  ```
- Fix route in dashboard.html

  ```
   <!-- below is dashboard.html page -->
   <div ng-controller="app">
      <h1>Page_3</h1>
          <div><a href='page_3.html'>page_3</a></div>
    </div>
  ```

[Click here for the demo / jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/vakujokara)

Other/suggestions: as [Zack Briggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462603/zach-briggs) have suggested; using controller syntax in routes would help you come up with better code structure / design in router config, [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), or [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Also putting everything in one place is often a bad idea for a growing project.